# Problems using react-router for basic routing after installing it on a new project

Tags: javascript, html, react-router, reactjs

About four days ago, I created a project with `react-router`. I installed everything as normal, following [this guide](https://edspencer.net/2016/03/20/a-new-stack-for-2016-getting-started-with-react-es6-and-webpack/). I then installed `react-router` via the recommended method in the official Github readme.  For some odd reason, it wouldn't render any of my components until I moved the route to my `index.js` file in my root directory, where it began to work. Before, the route was located inside of my `app.jsx` file.

Today, I decided that I wanted to create a small portfolio site for myself, since I feel like I'm understanding the basics of React. I installed everything like I did before, w/ versions `3.0.0` and `15.3.2` of `react-router` and `react / react-dom` respectively. The versions have not changed since my last project a  few days back. However, it seems like `react-router` is no longer working for some reason, showing no errors in my console, and I've spent hours now searching Google and Stack Overflow for solutions. My code is super bare-bones currently, with my `index.js` file looking like the following, without the use of `react-router`:

```
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
    }
}

const Home = () =>
    <p>Hello</p>;

render(
    <App><Home /></App>,
    document.getElementById('main'))
```

I understand that I should be moving towards more functional programming, but for the time being I have `App` written as a class, for testing reasons. Now, why would the above code work correctly, but the code snippet below will not produce any results?

```
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory} from 'react-router'

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
    }
}

const Home = () =>
    <p>Hello</p>;

render(
    (<Router history="hashHistory">
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        </Route>
    </Router>),
    document.getElementById('main'))
```

I really do not think I'm misunderstanding `react-router` in any way. I've tried wrapping the route in `()`, as I've seen in some tutorials, but that didn't make a difference -- obviously.

Is there something wrong with my code? or could it be something else? If there is any more information I can provide for you guys, let me know. I can take some screen shots or something, if that would help any of you out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change

```
<Router history="hashHistory">
```

to

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
```

Router is expecting history to be an objetct, not string:

```
var Router = _react2.default.createClass({
  displayName: 'Router',

    propTypes: {
    history: object

    (...)
});
```

Comment: This actually was not the problem. Though, that was a bug I quickly noticed after I posted this. The issue was actually running it through `webpack-dev-server`. When I simply run `webpack` and boot the `index.html` through my browser, it seems to work fine. Would you know why that is?